# Convert $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{4}{n}\sqrt{2+\frac{4k}{n}}$ into a definite integral.

Tags: definite-integrals, riemann-sum

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{4}{n}\sqrt{2+\frac{4k}{n}}$$
So going through this, I found out $a=2$ and $\Delta x = 4$, which got me $ \int_2^6 \sqrt{2+\frac {4k} n} dx $. If this is correct, how do I then evaluate this?

Comment: Please, take time to write correctly your question.

Comment: ohmygod I formatted this horribly ther were so many errors, thank you!

Comment: Ohyourgod, take much time.

Comment: wait I formatted it correctly now

Comment: The summation is over index $k$, however $k$ does not appear in the function.

Comment: ahhhHHHH thanks so much now It's corect

Comment: How can you integrate  $ \sqrt{2+4\frac{k}{n} }$  with respect to $x$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If you do some rearrangements, you get
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4}{n} \sum_{k=0}^n \sqrt{2 + 4\frac kn}$$
This is a riemann sum of the form $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} f(\frac kn)$. The correct definite integral would be $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$, which in this case is
$$4\int_0^1 \sqrt{2 + 4x} dx$$
Evaluating this integral is simple. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

In this case $\Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n}$ and $x_k = a+k \Delta x$ with $a=2$, so $b=6$ and $x_k = 2 + \frac{4k}{n}$.